# Как вернуть старое поведение Ctrl+Click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

В Visual Studio 2017 по крайней мере в C# стали обрабатывать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> как Go To Defenition, но я умею нажимать <kbd>F12</kbd>, которое делает то же самое.

Раньше <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> использовалось для выделения всего слова - как вернуть это поведение?

Comment: Нашел это: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18921634-option-to-disable-ctrl-click-go-to-definition

Comment: @defaultlocale, да, оно! Ответ напишешь? Могу скриншот подкинуть, если надо.

Comment: Написал. Если скриншот с русифицированной студии, то был бы за него очень благодарен, пока взял скрин из ответа на форуме.

Comment: @defaultlocale, да, я уже увидел и плюсанул, но для принятия минимальное время не прошло. Студия у меня тоже английская.

Comment: а двойной click чем хуже?

Comment: @4per, можно нажать ctrl, щёлкнуть в любом месте слова и продолжить выделять текст дальше (вот скринвидео: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YoWj.gif) - очень удобно. А с двойным кликом так не получится. Ну и при копипасте Ctrl и так под рукой.

Comment: Ну да, удобно. Вот только я попробовал в VS17 и там тоже работает, если  было движение между ЛКМ MouseDown и ЛКМ MouseUp

Comment: @4per, ну я и для одного слова применяю, если Ctrl под рукой (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ на [похожий вопрос в форуме поддержки](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18921634-option-to-disable-ctrl-click-go-to-definition).

> In Visual Studio 2017, you can change the Ctrl+Click behavior under Tools > Options > TextEditor > General about halfway down the pane (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoTj7bKlFWmkjiMw_TyCcwwxmwJM). This should allow you to revert back to the previous behavior or choose a different modifier key to activate Go To Definition with the mouse.
>
> **Перевод:** В Visual Studio 2017 вы можете изменить поведение Ctrl+Click через меню Tools > Options > TextEditor > General посередине панели находится опция:

[image: Сркиншот]

> которая должна вернуть старое поведение. Также можно выбрать другую клавишу для перехода с помощью мыши.